# Does OAuth2Decorator store user Credentials and renew Tokens?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm working with the [`OAuth2Decorator()`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/platforms/google_app_engine) and Pytgon  I'm in that stage where i'm still unsure of something about the App Engine. The documentation is not providing any info or I simply can't follow it. So:

> Does OAuth2Decorator() store user Crediantials?
>
> Does OAuth2Decorator() retrieve new tokens automatically?

Conside this following example.:

```
decorator = OAuth2Decorator(...)
service = build("drive", "v2")

class AppHandler(BaseHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_aware
    def get(self):
        if decorator.has_credentials():
            init = service.files().list().execute(decorator.http())
            items = init['items']
            context = {'data': getitems(items)}
            self.render_response('index.html',**context)
        else:
            url = decorator.authorize_url()
            self.redirect(url)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The credentials get stored as CredentialsModel in the datastore.

Provided the access that's requested is 'offline' (I believe this is the default), then there will be a 'refresh token' stored alongside the temporary access-token. If a request is made with a credentials-wrapped Http client, then upon receiving a response that indicates the access token has expired, the client make a request to get a new access token automatically, and then the original request will be retried with the new access token, which will then be stored in place of the expired one.